# Does overpassAPI setup supports importing from osm.pbf file

Tags: openstreetmap, overpass-api

Does overpassAPI setup supports importing from osm.pbf file? The docs are only mentioning the use of planet.osm file.

Answer (score 3):

We have a prototype which can directly import data from pbf. However, the official version doesn’t support it, and there are no current activities to include pbf. You would need to use an external tool to convert pbf to Osm format and pass the results via a pipe to Overpass.